# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged event fails over the internet

Tags: asp.net

I have two ASP.net DorpDownLists in a web page. When the selection changes on the first drop down list, the client is expected to do a postback and the the server will populate the second drop down list based on the selection.

I have this page working as expected on the intranet but when it is accessed from the internet, the postback happens(I have verified the __EVENTTARGET with Burp Proxy and it is working) but the server is not calling the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Anybody ever faced something similar? Any suggestions or recommendations on how to resolve?

Comment: maybe fail to verify the event, or maybe you have disabled the verification of event and after fail no error is throw

Comment: Thanks mate. Fixed the problem. There were no code issues.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to resolve this issue. Not quite sure what is going wrong but the following method fixed this.

The production set us for this application is as follows

```
IIS------FooBarApp(Virtual Directory for Intranet/Basic Auth)
     |
     |---FooBarApp_RP(Virtual Directory for Reverse proxy/Windows Integrated Auth)
```

Both the virtual directories map to the same physical location.
When accessed from 'FooBarApp' vistual directory, everything works fine but PostBack events from a specific drop down list were not detected by the server when accessed from the internet through 'FoobarApp_RP' virtual directory.

The web server admin just unlinked the Physical location of the 'FooBarApp_RP' virtual directory and re-established it. After that everything started working.

Don't know why it worked but it worked. I'd greatly appreciate if someone can shed some light on it.

Thanks